# Angular Firebase App hosted successfully in Google Cloud Platform. But the site gives an error

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Angular Firebase App hosted successfully in the Google Cloud Platform. But the site functionalities give an error and firebase functionalities are not working.

Error: @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.21.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=failed-precondition]: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Datastore Mode projects.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: Having the same issue, in my case it was working good with Firestore Native mode in a dev environment.

Once we created a new firebase project (for firebase prod environment) the default Database mode is not Firebase Native anymore but DataStore mode, which, as far as I know, it has different syntax and I will have to rewrite my queries code... nightmare.

I am strongly looking for a solution for this matter.
Any finding will be updated here.

Comment: https://youtu.be/SYG-BgXoJFQ

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/firestore-or-datastore?_ga=2.243031424.-349412829.1585610860#choosing_a_database_mode